# Redefine file extension associations in Sublime text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

I have noticed that Sublime text 2 by default associates files with `*.scm` and `*.ss` extensions with `lisp` language. But it's `scheme` actually.
Is it possible to redefine this association somehow (in config maybe)?

Currently, to get the correct syntax highlighting I just go to `View -> Syntax -> Scheme` every time I open `scheme` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extension associations are based on syntax highlighting schemes.

To remove unwanted associations, open ST2 and choose *Preferences → Browse Packages...*, a folder with packages will open. Find the incorrectly detected package (in this case *Lisp*) and open a *.tmLanguage* file (*Lisp.tmLanguage*) in ST2. It's first lines look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>comment</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>fileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>lisp</string>
        <string>cl</string>
        <string>l</string>
        <string>mud</string>
        <string>el</string>
    </array>
(...)
```

Those strings in lines 9-13 are file extensions that ST2 will associate with Lisp. You can remove some of those lines (place the cursor on unwanted line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>), changes will be applied immediately when you save the file.

To add new associations, open a *.tmLanguage* file from a package and add new strings among those already defined.

Answer (score 3):

View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as ...

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered in StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8014142/1346682

> In the current version of Sublime Text 2 (Build: 2139), you can set the syntax for all files of a certain file extension using an option in the menu bar. Open a file with the extension you want to set a default for and navigate through the following menus: `View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... ->[your syntax choice]`.

Valid also for the current latest version (Build: 3065).

Comment: tks, thumb up (y)